# Angular router-outlet is delaying to render components

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet

I am developing an Angular 6 app, my  is typically showing route connected components. But when page loads(when reloading Ctrl+R/F5),  is delaying to load components;

```
<div [loading]="loading">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <div id="pageContentWrapper">
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Here is my code; app-header and app-footer is rendered instantaneously but  is delaying render. Any ideas why it is delaying to render?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in stackblitz.com?

Comment: @alt255 I am afraid, I can not reproduce it, I was wandering is there were any theories about delaying the render of router-outlet

Comment: What is `[loading]`? Is it some directive?

Comment: [loading] is, while the loading variable is true, the page is loading, no action can be taken. when loading is false, loading animation goes off

Answer (score 0):

It's rather difficult to get help with no code provided, the important bits are not included in your post. However, I am going to take a risk... it looks like what you are trying to do is make a loading screen for a feature but not going about it correctly.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
        // siteLoading(true);
      } else if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
        // siteLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }
```